# Pandas : interpolate a dataframe and replace values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, interpolation, curve

For each column of a dataframe, I did an interpolation using the pandas function "interpolate" and i'm trying to replace values of the dataframe by values of the interpolated curve (trend curve on excel).

I have the following dataframe, named data

```
        0      1
0   0.000  0.002
1   0.001  0.002
2   0.001  0.003
3   0.003  0.004
4   0.003  0.005
5   0.003  0.005
6   0.004  0.006
7   0.005  0.006
8   0.006  0.007
9   0.006  0.007
10  0.007  0.008
11  0.007  0.009
12  0.008  0.010
13  0.008  0.010
14  0.010  0.012
```

I then did the following code:

```
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    data[i].interpolate(method="polynomial",order=2,inplace=True)
```

I thought that inplace would replace values but it don't seems to work. Does someone knowns how to do that?

Thanks and have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in fact working with scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

I created a mini text file with some crazy values so you can see how interpolate is working.

File looks like this,

```
0,1
0.0,.002
0.001,.3
NaN,NaN
4.003,NaN
.004,19
.005,234
NaN,444
1,777
```

Here is how to import and process your data,

```
df=pd.read_csv('datafile.txt, header=0)

for column in df:
  df[column].interpolate(method="polynomial",order=2,inplace=True)

print(df.head())
```

the dataframe now looks like this,

```
       0           1
0  0.000000    0.002000
1  0.001000    0.300000
2  2.943616  -30.768123
3  4.003000  -70.313176
4  0.004000   19.000000
5  0.005000  234.000000
6  0.616931  444.000000
7  1.000000  777.000000
```

Also,
if you mean you want to interpolate between the points in your dataframe, that is something different.

Something like that would be,

```
df1 = df.reindex(df.index.union(np.linspace(.11,.25,8)))
df1.interpolate('index')
```

the results of that look like,

```
    0        1
0.00  0.00000  0.00200
0.11  0.00011  0.03478
0.13  0.00013  0.04074
0.15  0.00015  0.04670
0.17  0.00017  0.05266
0.19  0.00019  0.05862
0.21  0.00021  0.06458
0.23  0.00023  0.07054
0.25  0.00025  0.07650
1.00  0.00100  0.30000
```

Comment: In my case columns names are int ! It don't seems to work better. Where do you use numpy?

Comment: my column names are integers as well. I tell Pandas read_csv that the header are the column names on line 0 with header=0.  I edited to show the output data, I also removed importing numpy because it was needed.